# Combine multiple email addresses (in separate cells) into one cell (separated by comma) Google Sheets or Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to combine multiple cells with email addresses into one cell where emails are separated by commas.

I've used this formula:

```
=P2 & ", " & Q2 & ", " & R2 & ", " & AD2 & ", " & AE2 & ", " & AF2
```

But only two cells have emails, so the result is this:

```
, name1@domain.com, , , name2@domain.com,
```

How do I fix this? (Remove the redundant commas; bypass the empty cells; other solution.)

Comment: put spaces properly to make the formular readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `IF` functions as follows:

```
=IF(P2<>"",P2&", ","") & IF(Q2<>"",Q2&", ","") & IF(R2<>"",R2&", ","") & IF(AD2<>"",AD2&", ","") & IF(AE2<>"",AE2&", ","") & IF(AF2<>"",AF2,"")
```

This has a possibility of having an extra comma at the end, which you can remove using the following:

```
=IF(RIGHT(string,1)=",",LEFT(string,LEN(string)-1),string)
```

where `string` is the output of the previous formula (or any other string).

Rolled up into one ugly formula, it would look like this:

```
=IF(RIGHT(IF(P2<>"",P2&", ","") & IF(Q2<>"",Q2&", ","") & IF(R2<>"",R2&", ","") & IF(AD2<>"",AD2&", ","") & IF(AE2<>"",AE2&", ","") & IF(AF2<>"",AF2,""),1)=",",LEFT(IF(P2<>"",P2&", ","") & IF(Q2<>"",Q2&", ","") & IF(R2<>"",R2&", ","") & IF(AD2<>"",AD2&", ","") & IF(AE2<>"",AE2&", ","") & IF(AF2<>"",AF2,""),LEN(IF(P2<>"",P2&", ","") & IF(Q2<>"",Q2&", ","") & IF(R2<>"",R2&", ","") & IF(AD2<>"",AD2&", ","") & IF(AE2<>"",AE2&", ","") & IF(AF2<>"",AF2,""))-1),IF(P2<>"",P2&", ","") & IF(Q2<>"",Q2&", ","") & IF(R2<>"",R2&", ","") & IF(AD2<>"",AD2&", ","") & IF(AE2<>"",AE2&", ","") & IF(AF2<>"",AF2,""))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Alexis, for taking the time!! That's exactly what I needed, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: First, adds helper columns for each possible mail address column, use `IF` formula to get comma appended to each non-empty string, otherwise empty string is returned. For example, formula of helper column for P2 is `=IF(P2<>"", P2&",", "")`. Then concatenates above helper column together.

Option 2: Concatenates all your string as you did before, then substitutes multiple commas into one comma use regex, as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280008/excel-how-do-i-replace-text-by-using-a-wildcard

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less tortuous method would be to use this formula, which avoids the need to strip anything out, because it only gets added in wherever the cells being referenced contain anything:

```
=IF(P2<>"",","&P2,"")&IF(Q2<>"",","&Q2,"")&IF(R2<>"",","&R2,"")&IF(AD2<>"",","&AD2,"")&IF(AE2<>"",","&AE2,"")&IF(AF2<>"",","&AF2,"")
```